# How do I Dynamically set properties from the name in a parent class?

Tags: c#, linq, class, reflection

How do I dynamically set the "Name" properties of each of the AlarmModel's as the name of the model (i.e. HardwareFault) from the parent class?

```
public class NotificationModel
{
    public string UnrelatedProperty { get; set; }  // any solution should ignore other properties.

    public AlarmModel HardwareFault{ get; set; }

    public AlarmModel TimeoutFault { get; set; }

    public AlarmModel GenericFault { get; set; }
}

public class AlarmModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public bool isEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool isSilenced { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the `Name` property of each `AlarmModel` to the name of the property in the parent `NotificationModel`?

If that is the case, you could do something like this:

```
public class NotificationModel
{
    private AlarmModel _hardwareFault;

    private AlarmModel _timeoutFault;

    private AlarmModel _genericFault;

    public string UnrelatedProperty { get; set; }  // any solution should ignore other properties.

    public AlarmModel HardwareFault
    { 
        get => _hardwareFault; 
        set
        {
            _hardwareFault = value;
            SetName(value);
        }
    }

    public AlarmModel TimeoutFault 
    {
        get => _timeoutFault; 
        set
        {
            _timeoutFault= value;
            SetName(value);
        }
    }

    public AlarmModel GenericFault 
    {
        get => _genericFault; 
        set
        {
            _genericFault= value;
            SetName(value);
        }
    }

    private void SetName(AlarmModel model, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        model.Name = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `private SetName` missing return type of `void` . Also I suggest add a null-check for `model.Name` (e.g. `if (model is not null) model.Name = propertyName;`) to avoid `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **already initialized** `NotificationModel` with also already initialized `HardwareFault`, `TimeoutFault`, `GenericFault` properties, you can use this example:

```
var notificationModel = new NotificationModel()
{
    HardwareFault = new AlarmModel(),
    GenericFault = new AlarmModel(),
    TimeoutFault = new AlarmModel()
};

notificationModel?.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "AlarmModel") // Or p.PropertyType == typeof(AlarmModel)
                                            .ToList().ForEach(alarmModelProperty =>
{
    // Get AlarmModel property instance
    var alarmModelInstance = alarmModelProperty.GetValue(notificationModel);
    // Get Name property
    var nameProperty = alarmModelIntance?.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
    // Set Name property value with name of AlarmModel property
    nameProperty?.SetValue(alarmModelInstance, alarmModelProperty.Name);
});
```

If you have **already initialized** `NotificationModel`, but **without** initialized `HardwareFault`, `TimeoutFault`, `GenericFault` properties, you can use this example:

```
var notificationModel = new NotificationModel();

notificationModel?.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "AlarmModel") // Or p.PropertyType == typeof(AlarmModel)
                                            .ToList().ForEach(alarmModelProperty =>
{
    // Initialize new AlarmModel 
    var alarmModelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(alarmModelProperty.PropertyType);
    // Get Name property of AlarmModel
    var nameProperty = alarmModelInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
    // Set Name property of AlarmModel
    nameProperty?.SetValue(alarmModelInstance, alarmModelProperty.Name);
    // Set AlarmModel property of NotificationModel
    alarmModelProperty.SetValue(notificationModel, alarmModelInstance);
});
```

If you need full initialization with Reflection, you can use this example:

```
var notificationModelType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "NotificationModel"); // Or type == typeof(NotificationModel)
if (notificationModelType is null) // No NotificationModel found in current assembly
    return;

// Initializing NotificationModel
var notificationModel = Activator.CreateInstance(notificationModelType);

notificationModel?.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "AlarmModel") // Or p.PropertyType == typeof(AlarmModel)
                                            .ToList().ForEach(alarmModelProperty =>
{
    // Initialize new AlarmModel 
    var alarmModelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(alarmModelProperty.PropertyType);
    // Get Name property of AlarmModel
    var nameProperty = alarmModelInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
    // Set Name property of AlarmModel
    nameProperty?.SetValue(alarmModelInstance, alarmModelProperty.Name);
    // Set AlarmModel property of NotificationModel
    alarmModelProperty.SetValue(notificationModel, alarmModelInstance);
});
```

If `NotificationModel` declared NOT in current assembly (so it won't be in `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()`) - you can search through all loaded assemblies in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`:

```
var notificationModelType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                                   .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                                                   .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "NotificationModel");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should move property "Name" to parent class. and try to extend/inherit it to child class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).